# python incorrect rounding with floating point numbers

Tags: python, rounding

```
>>> a = 0.3135
>>> print("%.3f" % a)
0.314
>>> a = 0.3125
>>> print("%.3f" % a)
0.312
>>>
```

I am expecting 0.313 instead of 0.312
Any thought on why is this, and is there alternative way I can use to get 0.313?

Thanks

Comment: Search for `IEEE 754` and `round to even`. The rounding is *not* wrong. It conforms to the standard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python 3 rounds according to the IEEE 754 standard, using a [round-to-even](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Rounding_rules) approach.

If you want to round in a different way then simply implement it by hand:

```
import math
def my_round(n, ndigits):
    part = n * 10 ** ndigits
    delta = part - int(part)
    # always round "away from 0"
    if delta >= 0.5 or -0.5 < delta <= 0:
        part = math.ceil(part)
    else:
        part = math.floor(part)
    return part / (10 ** ndigits) if ndigits >= 0 else part * 10 ** abs(ndigits)
```

Example usage:

```
In [12]: my_round(0.3125, 3)
Out[12]: 0.313
```

---

**Note:** in python2 rounding is always away from zero, while in python3 it rounds to even. (see, for example, the difference in the documentation for the `round` function between 2.7 and 3.3).

Comment: Fails on: my_round(4354788000,-9)  -> 3999999999.9999995

Comment: @VincentAlex I'm pretty sure I wrote this code 8 years ago assuming `ndigits >= 0`. Anyway the issue is that you are hitting float limits. If you check the code you end up on the `return` line of `my_round` with `4 / (10 ** (-9))` which should return the correct result but it doesn't. You can easily check for the sign of `ndigits` and use `part * 10 ** abs(ndigits)` for the negative cases and this seems to work better.

Answer (score 3):

If you need accuracy [don't use float](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), use [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> d = Decimal('0.3125')
>>> getcontext().rounding = ROUND_UP
>>> round(d, 3)
Decimal('0.313')
```

or even [Fraction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
print '%.3f' % round(.3125,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same incorrect rounding

`round(0.573175, 5)` = 0.57317

My solution

```
def to_round(val, precision=5):
    prec = 10 ** precision
    return str(round(val * prec) / prec)
```

`to_round(0.573175)` = '0.57318'

Answer (score 0):

Since `round()` doesn't work correctly, I used the LUA approach instead:

```
from math import floor
rnd = lambda v, p=0: floor(v*(10**p)+.5)/(10**p)
```

Testing:

```
>>> round( 128.25, 1 )
128.2
>>> rnd( 128.25, 1 )
128.3
>>>
```

To not conflate with other answers
Other tests include:

```
>>> rnd = lambda v, p=0: round(v*(10**p))/(10**p) # hairetdin's answer
>>> rnd( 128.25, 1 )
128.2
>>> print( '%.3f' % round(128.25,1) ) # Tushar's answer
128.200
```

Other details:

The duplicate processing of `10**p` is negligible in performance from storing and referencing a variable.