# 'Proper' rounding in Python, to 3 decimal places

Tags: python, python-2.7

I may be missing something essential, but I can't figure out a way to 'properly' round floats/Decimals in Python (2.7), at least to three decimal places.  By 'properly' I mean that 1.2225 should round to 1.223, and 1.2224 should round to 1.222.

I know `round` won't work for floats in Python, by design, but I can't seem to get `Decimal` to behave as expected, nor the `ceil` function.  Looking for built-in functionality rather than custom function workarounds preferably, but open to both.

```
>>> x = 1.2225                                   # expected: 1.223
>>> round(x, 3)               
1.222                                            # incorrect

>>> from math import ceil

>>> ceil(x * 1000.0) / 1000.0
1.223                                            # correct
>>> y = 1.2224                                   # expected: 1.222
>>> ceil(y * 1000.0) / 1000.0 
1.223                                            # incorrect

>>> from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_UP, ROUND_HALF_UP

>>> x = Decimal(1.2225)
>>> x.quantize(Decimal('0.001'), ROUND_UP)
Decimal('1.223')                                 # correct
>>> y = Decimal(1.2224)
>>> y.quantize(Decimal('0.001'), ROUND_UP)
Decimal('1.223')                                 # incorrect

>>> y.quantize(Decimal('0.001'), ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal('1.222')                                 # correct
>>> x.quantize(Decimal('0.001'), ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal('1.222')                                 # incorrect
```

Is there a way to get the desired result?

Comment: idk why you'd expect **ceil** of 1222.4 to be 1222...

Comment: @Antti OP is just looking for a way to do “proper” rounding. That `ceil` example is just a way to show that `ceil` will not do the job properly. That does not imply that OP does not understand why that is the case.

Comment: Reopened the question. OP stated that they know that `round` by its design is not a solution. So the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473563/python-incorrect-rounding-with-floating-point-numbers) is not really helping. Instead, OP seems to be asking how to solve properly this with decimals (and why the attempted solution does not work).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `Decimal(1.2225)` is not what you expect it to be:

```
>>> Decimal(1.2225)
Decimal('1.2224999999999999200639422269887290894985198974609375')
```

You are using a *float* to the create the decimal, but that float is already too imprecise for your use case. As you can see, it’s actually a `1.222499` so it is smaller than `1.2225` and as such would correctly round *down*.

In order to fix that, you need to create decimals with correct precision, by passing them as strings. Then everything works as expected:

```
>>> x = Decimal('1.2225')
>>> x.quantize(Decimal('0.001'), ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal('1.223')
>>> y = Decimal('1.2224')
>>> y.quantize(Decimal('0.001'), ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal('1.222')
```

Comment: Ah!  That I haven't seen but it makes perfect sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I've been trying to figure out why my round() function was pants for over a week now. I feel enlightened!

Answer (score 2):

Here are three solution in this link, I hope this would help you exactly what you want to do.
https://gist.github.com/jackiekazil/6201722

```
from decimal import Decimal

# First we take a float and convert it to a decimal
x = Decimal(16.0/7)

# Then we round it to 2 places
output = round(x,2)
# Output to screen
print output
```

Comment: output = 2.29 while actual answer was "2.2857142857142856" so it's working.

Comment: While this is correct, you are kind of ignoring OP’s problem though…

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
float('{:,.3f}'.format(2.2225))
```

Comment: Compare your `'{:,.3f}'.format(2.2225)` with `'{:,.3f}'.format(1.2225)` (using OP’s input with a leading `1` instead of `2`).

Comment: True. Problems dealing with floats and rounding AS explained in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

let say to print

```
print(f"accuracy: {auc_score}, f1: {f1_score}")
```

we would like it to only show 3 precision point

```
print(f"accuracy: {auc_score:.3f}, f1: {f1_score:.3f}")
```