# How to round 3 decimals instead of 2 with django currencies template tags?

Tags: django

{% change_currency video.price CURRENCY.code %}
I have this template tag but it rounds the price to 2 decimal points when i change currency.
I want to make it to round to 3 decimals points.
Its from django-currencies library template tags

I tried to add|floatformat:”3” but nothing

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Proper' rounding in Python, to 3 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020797/proper-rounding-in-python-to-3-decimal-places)

Comment: Post the source code for the `change_currency` template tag.

Comment: @Selcuk https://github.com/panosl/django-currencies/blob/master/currencies/templatetags/currency.py this is the source code from the library for this template tag

Comment: I don't think you can change the number of decimals with the current implementation because of [this line](https://github.com/panosl/django-currencies/blob/master/currencies/templatetags/currency.py#L20). If you change it to `return calculate(..., decimals=3)` it could work. Maybe raise an issue on Github, or fork it?

Comment: My solution was to import this specific file and change it as you said , but it didn t work . Now i m thinking to import more files and change them and use them as my custom template tag