# round() with float is not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't figure out how the `round()` is working with the `float` data type, especially in the below-mentioned cases:

```
>>> round(23.4675,3)
23.468
>>> round(23.4625,3)
23.462
```

Here for `23.4675`, the `round()` rounds `23.4675` to `23.468` as expected, but it does not round `23.4625` to `23.463`. I check whether it rounds to the nearest even digit, but no

```
>>> round(23.4645,3)
23.465
>>> round(23.4635,3)
23.463
```

And it works fine sometimes :

```
>>> round(23.4653,2)
23.47
>>> round(23.4253,2)
23.43
>>> round(23.4653,2)
23.47
```

Again when I test repeatedly with more numbers, I get mixed results

```
>>> round(23.415,2)
23.41
```

Sometimes `round()` rounds `xx.xxx5` (say a float) to `xx.xx x+1` and sometimes it doesn't increment the last decimal digit.

I actually got mad while trying more and more numbers, still, I couldn't figure out why this confusion occurs.

I even searched for issues of `round()` and I found [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue39059).

This says that `round()` takes 2 digits for rounding like if `round(xx.xx53,2)`, it rounds off to `xx.x x+1`. but if it is `round(xx.xx5,2)`, it gives `xx.xx`. But this too didn't work for me. if it is `round(xx.xx5,2)` sometimes its `xx.x x+1` and sometimes it's `xx.xx`.

Kindly help me out in understanding. Thanks in advance

Note : I just need explanation not an alternative solution.

And I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473563/python-incorrect-rounding-with-floating-point-numbers). This again says that it rounds of to the nearest even digit. I mentioned in my question that it doesn't work.

Comment: Even in your own link, it answers your question: 

`as the docs you linked to explain, this is not a bug: \`round\` is giving the correct result in all cases (or at least, as correct as is possible given the use of binary floating-point).`

Comment: @GuyIncognito it's not rounding to nearest even digit. I even mentioned that in my question. Kindly check that. And I just need explanation and don't need any alternate solution

Comment: It's just floating point precision, it has to deal with how each number is represented internally

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)

Comment: `format(23.415,'.18f') == '23.414999999999999147'`.  Binary floating point can't represent some decimal numbers exactly and you can see that if you specify more digits after the decimal.  23.415 is really stored as shown, so the "nearest digit" for rounding to 2 digits is 1, not 2.  If you need decimal precision, use the `decimal` module.

Comment: Numbers that can be stored exactly are fractional powers of 2 such as 1/8 and 3/8, so `round(23.125,2) == 23.12` and `round(23.375,2) == 23.38` round to the even number as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The rounding algorithm used in computer science is not the traditional rounding but `round to even`. The reason is to avoid systematic bias when calculating with rounded numbers. In simple words, with the traditional rounding you would round all numbers that end with `5` up, which introduces a systematic error. With `round to even` method, some of the numers ending with `5` round up and some down, therefore in larger datasets the bias gets balanced.
Explanation [here](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2019/11/11/round-to-even.html#:%7E:text=The%20main%20reason,rounding%20since%201985.)